# polygon color changes automatically when zooming map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have implemented a google map using V3 js API. I am drawing about 500 zip code polygons inside the map. The colouring of the zip code polygons depends upon certain conditions which is working fine. Like I am assigning distinct colours to a set of zipcodes. But the problem is when I am zooming in the map some of the zipcode polygon colours getc changed. How can we fix it.

Here is the code

```
{% ifequal zip.rank 1 %}
    var fillColor = '#FF0000';
{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal zip.rank 2 %}
    var fillColor = '#FF00D3';
{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal zip.rank 3 %}
    var fillColor = '#BE4BAA';
{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal zip.rank 4 %}
    var fillColor = '#BE88B5';
{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal zip.rank 5 %}
    var fillColor = '#857081';
{% endifequal %}


var path = [
                {% for polycoord in zip.zip_info.zip_polygon %}
                    new google.maps.LatLng({{polycoord.1}}, {{polycoord.0}}),
                {% endfor %}
            ];
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(
    {
        path:path, 
        clickable:true,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.75,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: fillColor,
        fillOpacity: 1,
    }

);
polygon.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Posting the code for the color changing logic would help.

Comment: I have posted the code. Basically I am sending a flag from server side and depending on that flag I am setting the filcolor.

Comment: What does the HTML/javascript in the client/browser look like?  None of the code you posted looks like it should depend on zoom, do you have any code inside a event listeners that might effect the map objects?

Comment: Also, you have a "hanging comma" at the end of your Polygon definition that will cause problems in some (maybe all) versions of IE.

Comment: I have added further explanation to my original question. Can anyone pls help me out.